# Keep computer locked in a view-only state

Tags: 14.04, security, lock-screen, screensaver

Is there any way to keep my computer locked in a "view-only" state? I want to be able to see the screen, but if I want to control the computer, I'll have to enter my password.

I cannot move the computer to other room to keep only display accessible, because it's physically connected to other resources.

Comment: Would it be possible to take away the keyboard and mouse, then plug them back in when needed? :) (hopefully someone has a better suggestion than this!)

Comment: @NickWeinberg, no because the CPU, is locked in something like this http://www.sitedomecanico.com.br/Eshop.Admin/Imagens/sitedomecanico/rack_fechado.jpg.

Comment: @NickWeinberg I was thinking in something like an screensaver that doesn't start, but knows when I'm AFK for 10 minutes, so if after 10 minutes someone try to use the computer,  this little program has an hability to lock it out.

Comment: Possibly related to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17170/disable-keyboard-mouse-input-on-unix-under-x (on the Unix and Linux StackExchange)

Comment: @NickWeinberg, looks like you found it! I will test on monday and return here! thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the `xtrlock` package, available in the Ubuntu repositories. I think it will accomplish what you're looking for.

You can view its manual page online here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xtrlock.1x.html

> While xtrlock is running, the mouse and keyboard are grabbed and the mouse cursor becomes a padlock. Output displayed by X programs, and windows put up by new X clients, continue to be visible, and any new output is displayed normally. The mouse and keyboard are returned when the user types their password, followed by Enter.